# Application Is stop if i pressed Back Button In Android

Tags: android

i have created one application it contains 
Progress bar with maximum limit.if i press start for starting my progress bar progress bar starts in background and got message box in application only. But if i press BACK button then my application get stop..
i want my application running in background though i press BACK button..So please tell me how to achieve this..if want code of my application then let me know...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                moveTaskToBack(true);
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need to save the state of your android application when back button is pressed. (save all application data in onPause and reuse it when the application is started again) or use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to keep it running in the background when Android closes your app.

Something more convenient is an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) if your service is like a single task (for example a file upload or download). An IntentService will finish automatically after the task is over.

Also, make sure you are not doing any of these operations in the UI thread. If the thread is blocked for more than a certain amount of time then Android will think that your app is non-responsive and will force the user to close the app. Move all long running operations to another thread using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: thanks sir....please help me like this.....as i am new to Android app. development

Comment: No problem Danny. Lots of people to help you here. Make sure to accept their answers if you find them helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of Service as a solution for running it in background.

Comment: Go through this site.http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html                                          This is a good example that will help to demonstrate Service.

Comment: accept any of the answers that vl make others to answer ur questions

Answer (score 0):

@rohit If the android version is lower than 7 onBackPressed() is not yet implemented. Then use the following snippet and it should work.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (  Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) < 7 //Instead use android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
            && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // Take care of calling this method on earlier versions of
        // the platform where it doesn't exist.
        onBackPressed();
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // This will be called either automatically for you on 2.0
    // or later, or by the code above on earlier versions of the
    // platform.

    doSomething();
    return;
}
```